# Python 3 and cgi. Error image download from webbrowser

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi

My question is about Python 3 and Web CGI. I have a problem when download one image from the webbrowser, the image is downloaded, but with error format. This is my code ...

```
    src = "../public/downloads/test.png"
    name = "test.png"
    data = open(src, 'rb').read()
    print("Content-Type: image/png;")
    print("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="+name+";")
    print("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary;")
    print("Content-Length: " + str(os.stat(src).st_size)+";\r\n")
    print(data)
```

**The problem is solved:**

```
    src = "../public/downloads/test.png"
    name = "test.png"
    data = open(src, 'rb').read()
    print("Content-Type: image/png;")
    print("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="+name+";")
    print("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary;")
    print("Content-Length: " + str(os.stat(src).st_size)+";\r\n")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(data)
```

Comment: What do you mean bad format? What's wrong with the image that's downloaded?

Comment: Yes, the image is downloaded correctly, but in wrong format, the image is not saved in binary mode. If show the image content in notepad++ the content is ...

b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\xde\x00 ...

Comment: The image is saved in plain text.